# type checking seems to be subverted

Tags: typescript

```
function test(parm : number) {
    console.log(parm);
}

var x = '12';
test(x); //does not compile as expected.
test(<any>x); //no error or warning.
```

Why do I not get a compiler error on the last line?  Any reference to the docs would be helpful.

TIA

Comment: It can help if you read `any` back to yourself as: "This variable will satisfy *any* type", or in your particular case "*x* will satisfy *any* type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `<any>x` what you're doing is casting the variable `x` to type `any`. That is, you're telling the compiler "Hey, in this place, I know that `x` is *really* of type `any`!". The compiler assumes you're right and uses the new type you've given it for that call.

`any` is a special type in TypeScript - it means that the type could be anything and could even change types! For this reason, the compiler allows variables of type `any` to be used instead of any other type. So, while your function only accepts a parameter of type `number`, it will also accept a parameter of type `any`, because, of course, that `any` could really be a number.

This behaviour is shown in the [language specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) in Section 3.8.4 - *Assignment Compatibility* (pages 44-45):

> Types are required to be assignment compatible in certain
>   circumstances, such as expression and variable types in assignment
>   statements **and argument and parameter types in function calls**. S
>   is assignable to a type T, and T is assignable from S, if one of the
>   following is true...:
>
> - S and T are identical types.
> - **S or T is the Any type.**
> - ...

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I would have expected no error if I had typecast x to a number like this:  <number> x.  But in this case I am typecasting to a superclass which in a language like c# would have resulted in an error.

Comment: @MBeckius Like I said, it's a special case. I don't think it's strictly implemented as an OO superclass (as it certainly doesn't behave like one!). *Any* pretty much just turns off type checking entirely for a variable, it'll accept any assignment and be accepted into any method.

Comment: @MBeckius It's useful because, by default, everything is given the type `any` (unless type inference or annotation specifies otherwise, or it's a primitive). This means that nothing is type checked by default and you can use JavaScript code in TypeScript files without conversion. You also get a way to opt out of type checking for clever/crazy code.

Comment: >>This means that nothing is type checked by default and you can use JavaScript code in TypeScript files without conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  However the type checking in this case still seems inverted from languages like C# where the parameter would be constrained to that type or a subclass.

Comment: TypeScript uses normal rules for a subtype here, but the rule is suspended for `any`. If you wanted to think of this more like `Object` in C#, you could cast to `{}` instead, which would fail as expected.

Answer (score 2):

OK. Directly from the [specs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) (on page 23):

> All types in TypeScript are subtypes of a single top type called the
>   `Any` type.

So you're in place of *type* `numeric` you're using its *supertype* `any`. No conflict.

Comment: In my experience in statically typed languages, passing in a supertype when a subtype is expected is not valid.

Comment: @MBeckius I believe that this is the essence of polymorphic behavior, which is one of the three characteristics of OO language.  You are passing the same physical object - you just declare it differently.